# Div disappearing behind footer

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I am trying to make a little image gallery with an option to scroll. If I set a size for the height of the gallery, then it will look incredibly awkward on bigger monitors with a bunch of space below it.

I think the bigger issue is that I've made a lot of adjustments to the whole website just to make sure the footer works, and I definitely don't like how it's implemented, though at this stage I don't see another way. So for now I guess I really just want help with the gallery working, though if anyone has any suggestions for making footers work in future sites, I'd love suggestions.

All right, here's my HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="content_wrapper">

    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="gallery">

</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer_wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}



#gallery {
    height: 400px;
    width: 770px;
    background-color: rgba(247,247,247,0.8);
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#gallery img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0.2em 1em;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #00F;
    border-width: 1px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-size: cover;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /* was: 0 0 -43 0 */
    overflow: fixed;
}

#content_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px -41px 0px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: fixed;
}

#header {
    background-size: cover; 
    height: 7em;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px #000;
    border-top: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 4em;
    margin-top: -4.07em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #2A64A7;
    border-top: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

Sorry for all the code, but I'm kind of at my wit's end. Whenever I fiddle with something, it gets lost behind the footer, or it doesn't look good on a big screen. I'll keep this up to date with anything I figure out.

Thanks in advance for any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: (I slightly changed your markup)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vFrTf/1/)**

### Markup

```
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <div id="gallery">
</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: -7em 0 -4em;
    padding: 7em 0 4em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#header
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    background-size: cover; 
    height: 7em;
    box-shadow: 4px 2px 5px #000;
}
#footer
{

    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #2A64A7;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestions make my site do really odd things. So, on the homepage, where there is no gallery, I have no space above the header, there's a scrollbar, and there is a bunch of space below the footer that obviously shouldn't be there. On my gallery page, it is the same, except there is some space above the header. So unfortunately this doesn't work for me. (And I altered both my HTML and my CSS to reflect your suggestions.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
z-index
```

attribute.  Items with a higher z-index get shown on top.

Comment: This didn't change a thing, unfortunately. The problem is not so much that the gallery isn't going on top of the footer, it's that it is allowed to go beyond the top of the footer. I want it to extend as close as it can to the top of the footer, stop, then resort to making a scrollbar to show the rest of the content.

Comment: Use `overflow:scroll;` then.